# Head of Household and dependent status tracking with GnuCash

Tags: united-states, taxes, gnucash, dependents

I would like to use GnuCash (if possible) to track my status as head of household and my mother's status as a dependent. The rules are in IRS Publication 501 (mostly worksheet 2). My ultimate goal is a report or a set of accounts that clearly shows how much I have contributed to each expense account vs. my mother.

This causes 5 unique sub-sets of expenses, which I need to be able two group into to major sets of expenses: Head of household (Hoh) and Dependent (Dep). All but two are simple to handle and are unique to a major set of expenses. The exceptions are:

1. Hoh and Dep expense she paid.
2. Hoh and Dep expence I paid.

So for example: I paid $100 for "food on premise" that would be an expense in Head of household (Hoh) account as $100 and as an expense in Dependent (Dep) account as $100.

This problem doesn't fit into double booking accounting as far as I can tell. If this can be solved with GnuCash, great; if not, what is the standard practice for tracking something like this (one expense that needs to be summed in two places)?

To add to the fun here is a visual breakdown of the expenses in a 
[Venn diagram explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHoPE.png). Items marked I1, I2, I3 are my expenses while H1 and H2 are her expenses. Items I2 and H2 are the cause of my grief.

Comment: Is there a logical place to put a credit on the Dep side?